# Spread operators with variable as Rest Parameter

Tags: javascript

I want to filter `data` using spread operator. I have a function that has `category` as its argument.

The problem is when I pass `category` as arg to the spread operator I got an obvious error:
The symbol "category" has already been declared.

How can I use `category` instead of the hardcoded "Headlines"?

```js
const data = {
    "subscription": {
        "Headlines": ["headline1", "headline1"],
        "News": ["news1"],
    }
}
const category = "Headlines";
// const { category, ...rest } = data.subscription; This does not work.
const { Headlines, ...rest } = data.subscription; // This works.
const updatedData = {...data, subscription: rest};
console.log(updatedData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to deconstruct a dynamic property, you can use square brackets `[]` and assign the destructured value to a variable name:

```js
const data = {
  "subscription": {
    "Headlines": ["headline1", "headline1"],
    "News": ["news1"],
  }
};

const category = "Headlines";
const { [category]: categoryProp, ...rest } = data.subscription;

const updatedData = {...data, subscription: rest};
console.log(updatedData);
```

Comment: Hi. "Try this" isn't particularly useful. You should describe with links to documentation what you've done to solve the problem.